# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined (changing element classes on scroll)

Tags: jquery, scroll, typeerror

I went through some similar questions as to the `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined` error, but I could not figure out a solution to my own problem. In my JS file, there is this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('scroll', function() {
        var verticalPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
        $('#sitenav > ul > li > a').each(function() {
            if ( verticalPosition >= $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top - 85) {
                $('#sitenav > ul > li > a').not(this).parent().removeClass('current-menu-item'); // remove class from parent <li>
                $(this).parent().addClass('current-menu-item'); // add class to parent <li>
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The problem seems to be this line:

```
if ( verticalPosition >= $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top - 85) {
```

The code works fine, but I keep getting said error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefine

The number of found errors keeps increasing when scrolling, too. Any hints why the code works while I keep getting these errors and how to fix it?

This is the HTML piece the JS refers to:

```
<nav id="sitenav" class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 pull-right">
    <ul class="list-unstyled text-right">
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <!-- etc. -->
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: `$($.attr(this, 'href')).offset()` this is returning `null` or `undefined`

Comment: Can you explain why? I don't really understand why because I checked via `console.log($.attr(this, 'href'));` what it was returning and it was returning e.g. `#about` and `#contact`.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't without seeing a working example of you code. If you can set up a http://jsfiddle.net demo I can take a look